# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: unexpected_message

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2, sslsocketfactory

We're trying to make secure http communication between client an server.

The server provided the certificates, we took them, install them and we start running, the point is to exchange an exact number of messages simultaneously between the client and server consecutively, the problem that's driving us crazy is that between the requests, at **SSLHANDSHAKE** we get randomly the exception **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message** exactly  at **ServerHello** handshake phase, and i don't know how or why this is happening while it keeps working fine for 98% of the other requests.

[image]

it crashes at **step 2**.

**Transporter.java** : This is the class responsible for sending and receiving the data.

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;

        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.ProtocolException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.security.KeyStore;
        import java.util.ResourceBundle;
        import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
        import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
        import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
        import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
        import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
        import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
        import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
        import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
        import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

        public class Transporter {

            private static ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resourece_00");
            private static final String keystore = resource.getString("server_keystore");
            private static final String truststore = resource.getString("server_truststore");
            private static final String keypass = resource.getString("server_keystore_pwd");
            private static final String trustpass = resource.getString("server_truststore_pwd");

            // secure channel variables
            private static SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;

            public Transporter() {
                // setupSocketFactory();
            }

            static {
                try {
                    String protocol = "TLS";
                    String type = "JKS";

                    String algorithm = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
                    String trustAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();

                    // create and initialize an SSLContext object
                    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol);
                    sslContext.init(getKeyManagers(type, algorithm), getTrustManagers(type, trustAlgorithm), null);

                    // obtain the SSLSocketFactory from the SSLContext
                    sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private static KeyStore getStore(String type, String filename, String pwd) throws Exception {

                KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(type);
                InputStream istream = null;

                try {

                    File ksfile = new File(filename);
                    istream = new FileInputStream(ksfile);
                    ks.load(istream, pwd != null ? pwd.toCharArray() : null);
                } finally {
                    if (istream != null) {
                        istream.close();
                    }
                }

                return ks;
            }

            private static KeyManager[] getKeyManagers(String type, String algorithm) throws Exception {
                KeyStore ks = getStore(type, keystore, keypass);
                KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
                kmf.init(ks, keypass.toCharArray());
                return kmf.getKeyManagers();
            }

            private static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers(String type, String algorithm) throws Exception {
                KeyStore ts = getStore(type, truststore, trustpass);
                TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
                tmf.init(ts);
                return tmf.getTrustManagers();

            }

            public String sendToVD(String msg, String urll, Long timeOut) {

                byte[] bytes = msg.getBytes();
                HttpsURLConnection sconn = null;
                URL url = null;
                OutputStream out = null;
                BufferedReader read = null;
                String recu = null;

                try {

                    url = new URL(urll);
                    sconn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    sconn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession sslSession) {

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    sconn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
                    // sconn.setReadTimeout((timeOut.intValue()) * 1000);// set timeout
                    sconn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    sconn.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + bytes.length);
                    sconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
                    sconn.setDoOutput(true);
                    sconn.setDoInput(true);
                    // send POST data
                    // This is the crash location
                    out = sconn.getOutputStream();
                    // OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
                    out.write(bytes);
                    out.flush();
                    // logger.info("flush!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    // out.close();
                    read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sconn.getInputStream()));
                    String query = null;
                    recu = read.readLine();
                    while ((query = read.readLine()) != null) {
                        recu += query;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        // close all connections here
                        if (out != null)
                            out.close();

                        if (read != null)
                            read.close();

                        if (sconn != null)
                            sconn.disconnect();
                    } catch (Exception ce) {

                    }
                }
                return recu;
            }
        }
```

The function **sendToVD()** does the main work of the exchange between **the client** and **the server**.

At **Client-End** : 
A web application with **JSF** managing the front layer, spring managing the beans life cycle, the communication entry to the client is assured by **Servlets**.

The client is deployed in a **RedHat Linux** machine, all **TLS_VERSIONS** are enbaled, **JDK_8**.

At **Server-Side**: i can't post the detailed information about the target URL for security measures, but it follows the following pattern **https://ip:port/path**, and it supports **TLS_v1.2**.

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: try enabling logging: `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");`

Comment: I already made this option, and it keeps failing randomly at **ServerHello** HandShake step, with javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message.